# Determining environment python runs on

Tags: python, windows

I'm writing a python program that I want to run differently whether it runs on the windows command prompt or windows powershell. I was wondering if there was a way to determine the environment python runs on within the program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, there's a recipe [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578133-get-parent-process-pid-win32/) to get the parent process ID, which you should be able to adapt to get the parent process name, but it's probably not a good idea to make the behavior of the code rely on the shell program which started it. In what way did you want the program to run differently?

Answer (score 1):

First use [this code](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2013/01/python-get-parent-process-id-pid-in.html) to get your parent process id. Then call:

```
if ("powershell.exe" in os.popen("tasklist /fi \"PID eq %d\"" % parentPID).read()) {
    # We're a child of powershell!!
    ...
}
```

Though to be honest it's kind of strange to execute differently if you're being run by powershell. You should think seriously about WHY you want to do this and evaluate if you're doing something unnecessary.

If you want the platform instead (which is somewhat implied by your last statement), the platform module usually tells you what you want to know.

```
>> import platform
>> platform.architechture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

Note that from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) that it suggests you use `is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32` for Mac to determine 64 bit vs 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one solution. You can call some powershell command as Write-Host (echo equivalent in cmd) from Python code and get call result. If it fails is not PowerShell. (I can not test it now).

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously just add another parameter when calling your script.

When inside  the script, the `sys.args` variable gives you all the arguments passed to your script (first always being the name of the script).

There's also the library [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) which can help you with the job.....

What you're doing is not a good practice :P quite the opposite :) Anyway, don't take this too hard, I mean i don't know what you're trying to do, but it sounds like a dangerous idea.